# AWS - App not working/accessible with Elastic Beanstalk, autoscaling, and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I'm running an app in an elastic beanstalk environment. The software configurations are set to use Nginx as the proxy server for client connections, and use 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running Node.js. I have set up an autoscaling group behind an ELB (Port configuration is set to 80 (HTTP) forwarding to 8081 (HTTP), and my node app is set to listen on port 8081). In Route53, I've set an A record alias for the domain to point to the load balancer.

Now, when I try to browse to the index of my app, it hangs and after a minute or so stops making a request and displays a blank page.

Locally, the app runs just fine, and runs when I previously had it running on a single EC2 instance.

I've gotten to the point where I'm not even sure what I should be checking to resolve this issue. Any suggestions would definitely be helpful.